# Is it possible to include the service or protocol name in ufw status output?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ufw

When running `ufw status` on Ubuntu 18.04, I'd like to be able to see the service or protocol name e.g. http, IMAP. Is this possible just using a single command? So in a list like the following there would also be a column for service or protocol.

```
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
25/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
465/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
587/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
993/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
```

I prefer ufw as it is less complex than iptables and I'm not a seasoned sysadmin.

I can do something like `sudo ufw app info "Dovecot Secure IMAP"` which returns the port so am guessing one way would be to iterate over app list in a bash script.